# SSH Server Behavior

Tags: ssh

I am investigating what could be some odd behavior on a server of mine. I got notification that packets originating from my server are attacking SSH server ports on other servers.

While monitoring TCP traffic for SYN packets, I see the following (example):

> 03:43:41.759343 IP [local IP].22 > [remote IP].22: Flags [S.],

In other words, the local SSHD server, at local IP and local port 22, is sending a SYN packet to the remote SSHD server at remote IP and remote port 22, but I am not sure under what circumstance this would happen as normally the source port is a high port number.

I have tried to reproduce the packet with port forwarding, but so far cannot figure it out.

Cheers,
Geof.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I believe I could be wrong here. I just realized the above is not a SYN packet, but a SYN-ACK, which is normal. So never mind.